# How can i set the default menus for Rhomobile Application?

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

Currently on going for menu, it shows some options like sync, close, home.

Since i don't have any such functionality of sync, so i just need to be able to manage them. Or if i could able to add my own custom menu it would be quite well for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the default menu on the `application.rb` file. You can set the required default menu like below,

```
# default options menu
@default_menu = {
   "Home" => :home, 
   "Refresh" => :refresh, 
   "Close" => :close
}
```

Even you can set the custom menu as like this,

```
# default options menu
@default_menu = {
   "Home" => :home, 
   "Refresh" => :refresh, 
   "Close" => :close,
   "Custom" => '/app/MyModel'
}
```

Check here http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui#application-menu

Comment: Hmm Thanks SilverBlade